# Remove duplicates within groups conditional upon another variable

Tags: r

I have mock data that looks like this...

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c(rep("John Snow", 6), rep("Tyrion Lanister", 3), "Arya"),
                 Incident_Day = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,6),
                 DayFLAG = c(T,T,T,T,T,F,F,T,T,F))
df
              Name Incident_Day DayFLAG
1        John Snow            1    TRUE
2        John Snow            1    TRUE
3        John Snow            1    TRUE
4        John Snow            2    TRUE
5        John Snow            2    TRUE
6        John Snow            3   FALSE
7  Tyrion Lanister            1   FALSE
8  Tyrion Lanister            2    TRUE
9  Tyrion Lanister            2    TRUE
10            Arya            6   FALSE
```

The flag variable I have created flags all rows who, within each factor of `Name` (I know I have not created a factor variable in the example above), have the same `Incident_Day`. If this is not making sense, the data I am working with has multiple county agencies responding to an individual 911 call, each of which agency documents their own notes/incident reports. The individual may call on one day, then call again the following week, hence the repetition of the names and rows of data for each particular incident.

What I need to  do is go within both the `Name` and `Incident_Day` and de-deuplicate those who have `DayFLAG` as `TRUE`. I have been de-duplicating using the first instance so I think that would generally be an ok approach here. Ideal output would look like this.

```
> df_2
             Name Incident_Day
1       John Snow            1
2       John Snow            2
3       John Snow            3
4 Tyrion Lanister            1
5 Tyrion Lanister            2
6            Arya            6
```

Note- I do not care about the flag variable after this step as it will be de-duplicated so I can `!select` that column.

Thanks a ton for the help.

Comment: just do `unique(df[c('Name', 'Incident_Day')])`. Note that you do not need the `flag` column. Or simply do `unique(df)` if you have the 3 columns above. You do not need to create the flag column

Comment: `df[!duplicated(df),1:2]` should give you what you want

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. Might be a slightly mundane question, but is there a way to keep all the rows of data? Say this data frame has more rows pertinent to my analysis, how would I go about this such that all data is maintained after the `unique`? @Onyambu

Comment: am curious. you said you want to de-duplicate your data, yet you want to maintain all rows. am i missing something? what do you mean? you cannot remove the rows and then maintain them at the same time. the two are mutually exclusive

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is a duplication with 'Incident_Day' duplicated. In other words, what if John Snow has 2 of the same Incident_day (e.g. 3), and they are both FALSE?